# chatter feed tracking in salesforce?

Tags: chatter

Here is my requirement with chatter feed tracking:

```
i can create any record, in chatter field it shows starting with record name.

But i want to create with owner name in chatter field.
```

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: any body help me...

Comment: Did you want the name to be a link? Pretty sure you can do this with the ConnectAPI, so let me know and I'll write an example

Comment: Hi,any body help me regarding above screenshot in the record name(testrec) place i want owner name(salesforce) in chatter field.

Answer (score 0):

So that top header is always going to contain the creator information...but assuming that is a child object creating the feed item on its parent (that's what is looks like) - you can turn that auto creation off, and then create a post on the parent with a trigger on the child object...so something like this where Project__c refers to the parent record:

```
String s = userinfo.getname() + ' created a new Project';
ConnectAPI.ChatterFeeds.postFeedItem(null, ConnectApi.FeedType.Record, child.Project__c, s);
```

You could then message more useful information with rich text like mentions and links if required....